# Hide application in Market Place

Tags: android

I've googled this and have only found bad answers from a year or more ago, so I'm hoping things have changed.

I have developed an app for an apartment complex and they want only their residents to be able to download/see it in the marketplace.  It has to do with submitting maintenance requests and rental of common facilities, so, for obvious reasons they don't want just anyone seeing it, but want the convenience of the market place for distribution.

Can this be done without any of the goofy workarounds like garbling the name with a random string or changing the package name?

Comment: If it's hidden, there's not much convenience for the residents!  How would they find it?  A search term only they know?  Do a web page, click here to install app.

Answer (score 1):

Here you can do like below:
[Publishing on Google Play](http://developer.android.com/distribute/googleplay/publish/index.html) guide can show you the ins and outs and publishing to Google Play, but in a nutshell you upload the app to the Google Developer Console, and then publish it by going to `“Product Details”`, `“Publishing Options”`, `“Restrict Availability”` and checking off `“Make this application available only to users of my Google Apps domain”`. The app will then be sent to your Private Channel. Source: [TechRepublic](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/google-in-the-enterprise/deploy-private-android-apps-on-google-play/1898)

But here is My suggestion:

If it's for residents only then **you should upload APK some where on web** (Instead of uploading on play store) and give them web link. Residents will download APK directly from that link. There way your APK will be hidden from rest of the world.